# How to retry API calls when error returns?

Tags: node.js, api, asynchronous, repeat

I am making a code calling APIs using async.parallel

But sometimes API (i.e., cd.ChartData or ob.OrderBook in my code) returns error.

In that case, I want to repeat to call both of APIs even if only one API returns error.

How to do it?

```
async.parallel([
 function(callback){
    cd.ChartData(pair,end,days,function(ChartData){
     callback(null,ChartData);
  },
  function(callback){
    ob.OrderBook(pair, depth, function(OrderBook){
      callback(null,OrderBook);
    });
  }
],
  function(err, results){

})

module.exports.ChartData = function(pair, end, days, callback){

  request.get(url, function(error, response, body){
    if (error) {
      callback(error);
    } else {
      ChartData = JSON.parse(body);
      callback(ChartData);
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: check out https://github.com/DoSomething/node-request-retry

Answer (score 0):

We can use recursive function.
*** Please note that this pattern will cause the function to loop indefinitely when there is error from `request.get` so you might want to limit the times of retry.

```
//let's change your callback to standard Node.js callback format, callback(error, result)
//the first parameter to callback should always be null when there is no error but don't skip it
module.exports.ChartData = function(pair, end, days, callback) {
  request.get(url, function(error, response, body){
    if (error) {
      console.error(error);
      exports.ChartData(pair, end, days, callback); //keep trying if error occurs
    } else {
      ChartData = JSON.parse(body);
      callback(null, ChartData);
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It does Work!

Comment: One more... is it possible to repeat all API calls in async when errors?